# compare jquery datepicker with date in database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am newbie. I am working on asp.net website. I have added datepicker and it works fine. Now I want to get that date and compare it with date in my database. But I have no idea of how to do it. I also goggled but couldn't find any solution.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="reserve" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider();
    });

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#popupDatepicker').datepick();

    });

    function showDate(date) {
        alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker"  />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <div id='coin-slider' >
        <a target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
        <a>
           <img id="Img2" src="~/Images/ar1.jpg" alt="header1" height="120" runat="server" style="width: 110px"/>
           <img id="Img3" src="~/Images/ar2.jpg" alt="header1" height="120"  runat="server" style="width: 110px"/>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </a>
     </div>        
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: there are two ways you can do it

Comment: get the date from database and then compare it or compare it in stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Compare(Date1, Date2)` in code behind.

it'll give you differnce between the datetimes. Is this what you looking for

Comment: I am trying to compare the date selected by user on datepicker with the dates in the database. I do not know how to get the date on the datepicker selected by user.

Comment: Try this code

`if (popupDatepicker.Value.Trim().Length > 0)
{
 string[] ddmmyyyy = popupDatepicker.Value.Trim().Split(new char[] { '-', '/' });
 regDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ddmmyyyy[1] + "/" + ddmmyyyy[0] + "/" + ddmmyyyy[2]);
}`